# How to prevent the background image to get resized on soft keypad launch while other screen components are movable on keypad launch

Tags: android

I have Login Activity with a background image and a frame layout.

The framelayout will be replaced by a relative layout which contains three edit text boxes in the relative layout and a button at relative layout's bottom i.e., alignParentBottom = true.

When I focus on any of the edit text boxes the keypad raises ans I want all of them to move accordingly and the button at bottom should be immediately above the keypad so I am using adjustResize in my manifest, but this is making my background image to get resized i.e., compressed and displaying it within the visible space of the screen.

I need my background image not to move while all other components should be moving according to the screen.

If I use adjustPan the button which is aligned at parent bottom is not getting placed above the keypad and is invisible behind the softpad.

Please help me in this regard if anyone knows the way to resolve this requirement.

Thanks.

Comment: post your xml so that I can suggest the way to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"` to your activity in the manifest file.

Explained [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft):

> *adjustPan*
>
> The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft
>   keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned
>   so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users
>   can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable
>   than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to
>   get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.

Answer (score 0):

If it's top layer just instead of setting that layer background you set that activity custom theme with that background. That way it does't resize. At least that worked for me.

Comment: I have tried this one as said by you, but even then i find the same problem.